# When any changes in firebase database occurred app restarts

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that is using `Firebase database`, it's an old app. now I am doing some changes in but whenever I change something is database my app will restart.
here is the code how i push data to the firebase

```
databaseReference.child(otp)
                 .child("Guest List")
                 .child(stringDeviceId).setValue(guestModel)
                 .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                     Toast.makeText(AddGuestActivity.this, 
                      "Something went wrong, PLease try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                     Toast.makeText(AddGuestActivity.this, 
                       "A guest is Added to guest list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     //finish();
                     }
                 });
```

> Activity A(Splash 1)-> Activity B(OTP)-> Activity C(Splash
>   2)->Activity 4(Dashboard)->Activity 5(GuestList)-> Activity 6(Data
>   push to firebase)->

if i change database value then it will return to

> Activity C
>
> How i call to Activity 6

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity5.this, Activity6.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no error.

Comment: Is this in your launcher activity??

Comment: nope.. its not a launcher activity

Comment: Means when you'r changing the database the app restating ? Need to comment _finish()_

Comment: i need to finsh that activity after adding data to firbase but it will return to my other thn my previous activity

Comment: Show previous activity code ? May be in that activity you are finishing that activity too. You got my point ?@ShaifaliRajput

Comment: Just use _startActivityForResult_ . WIll solve your problem.

Comment: @Piyush problem solved.. actually I was using `addvalueeventlisnter` in Activity B and on `datachanged` move to Activity C and finish() Activity B that's why it always return to Activity C

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput That's why i was asking that any where you calling `finish()` ? Because that caused the issue somewhere. So i wanted to see your code. BTW good it is solved :)

Comment: @Piyush i need help regarding a query: I want to convert frame layout to bitmap but it returns null always. i have tried many solutions. can you help me?

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput What issue are you facing?? Can you show me part of snippet?

Comment: @Piyush right now i m in ofic

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput Sovled ur issue ?